# Angular fullstack Login functionality

Tags: angular-fullstack

I recently started working on **angular fullstack** and i got baffled in login module. I have email and password values that already exists in mongodb. Now i need to authenticate email & pwd before i fetch id and post authentication i should redirect to dashboard. Could anyone suggest or share any useful link that helps me out to achieve login functionality.

In index.js we have only router definitions..

```
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
```

Controller.show:

```
export function show(req, res) {
 User.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
.then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
.then(respondWithResult(res))
.catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Above code shows fetching **id** which works fine. But i need to cross check both email and pwd before we fetch id. I even tried to replace *id*  with email in index.js and controller.show which went vain. Even i didn't find any helpful examples/tutorials for this login module in internet. Looking for some help. I will be grateful if someone helps with solution/reference for this module.

Comment: It already checks email and password. Look at the Auth class.

Comment: Auth class?? i guess i missed this in documentation..let me check and verify..thanks for update..will get back to you if i require any help mark. Thanks

Comment: Just follow the trail of what happens when you click Login. You'll see it calls the Auth angular service that checks the username / password etc. Just takes a while to figure everything out. Took me a few weeks!

Comment: Hi mark..i didnt install auth module itself..thanks for suggesting..i did not find any clear documentation of using auth module in docs..any reference link to share??

Comment: Here is the `Auth` services https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/client/components/auth/auth.service.js

Comment: oh kk mark..let me try once..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As MarkPieszak suggests..

You can find the implementation of auth module clearly in 
 [github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo](http://%20github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo)

Make sure to install/select authentication module to install in your project when you run `yo angular-fullstack`.

Thanks MarkPieszak